# Watchdog errors with location = http://default/index.php

Tags: 7, log-messages

Looking through recent log messages, I've got a number of errors with no referrer listed, and showing location as being `http://default/index.php` (instead of `http://mysite.com/some/page`). They all seem to be triggered by "Anonymous" from localhost (127.0.0.1). Example screenshots are below.

Anyone know what kind of sense I should make of these entries?

Example screenshots: [image]

[image]

Here's one where location is not `http://default`, but `http://localhost`... again, why?

[image]

Comment: Are you runing cron via drush? `http://default` is the site uri drush will use if no one is provided.

Comment: @jonhattan: I AM running cron via drush, and suspect you put your finger on the source of my confusion. Do you have any idea about that last screenshot (which I just added), whichere location is not http://default, but http//localhost ?

Comment: It seems unrelated. Do you use http://localhost to access the site with the browser? This may explain that simply a file was not found.

Comment: @jonhattan: do you want to submit an answer (regarding drush cron) so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://default` is the site uri drush will use if no one is provided.

To provide a site uri you can pass options `-l` or `--uri` to drush: `drush -l http://example.com cron`.

Otherwise you can define and use an alias. See [drush example](http://drush.ws/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php) for reference. In a scratch:

File /etc/drush/aliases.drushrc.php:

```
<?php

$aliases['sitename'] = array (
  'root' => '/var/www/sitename',
  'uri' => 'http://example.com',
);
```

So the command to run is `drush @sitename cron`.

Comment: Thanks jonhattan. I was running cron via drush, and this turned out to be the reason for the `http://default` location in my watchdog messages, in my case.

Answer (score 3):

The first error seems to be due to a failing operation with the Backup & Migrate module. This module is probably configured to make a backup of your database on a scheduled (CRON) interval. As the error message suggests, increasing PHP's max_execution_time setting may help.

The second error you're seeing is due to a missing 'type' column in the file_managed database table. This field is usually added by the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) and/or [File Entity](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) modules. You likely updated these modules' code, but didn't run updates. Try running your update.php, or if that fails, disable, uninstall, and re-install the Media and File Entity modules.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Yuriy: much appreciated. Though my main question was not the source of the particular errors, but why I was seeing `http://default` as the location.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that your server is not set up for virtual hosting. If it receives an unqualified http request, it will go to the default, finding, in this case, index.php in your webroot. Since it is a direct request, there will be no referer. There is no DNS lookup necessary for local tasks. These messages are probably being kicked out by a cron or batch job.

I would not be concerned. But you certainly should address the missing column in the PDO exception.